# Restructure query to group by user_id and work out average time to hire

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query that works out the time to hire in days for all ad_id's based on a given USER_PK_ID

```
SELECT  ca.ad_id, r.CAND_ID, u.USER_PK_ID,  u.user_id, round(ca.CREATED_DT - r.submitted_dt, 1) as "Time to hire"
    FROM CANDAPPL_HISTORY_STAT_CHANGES ca
    JOIN ADVERTISEMENTS a on A.AD_ID = CA.AD_ID
    JOIN USERS u on a.user_id = U.USER_PK_ID
    JOIN REPLIES r on CA.CAND_ID = R.CAND_ID and CA.AD_ID = R.AD_ID 
    WHERE ca.acc_id = '150500'
    AND new_status = 'H'
    AND old_status != 'H'
    AND u.USER_PK_ID = '504407'
    AND (r.submitted_dt is not null or r.referrer like '%(ATSi)%')
    AND ca.CREATED_DT >= TO_DATE('2020-08-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND ca.CREATED_DT <= TO_DATE('2020-08-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Is it possible to restructure this query to group by user_id and work out the average time to hire across all ad's per user?

I have the following that groups by user_id and works out the number of roles filled by user_id

```
SELECT  u.USER_PK_ID,  u.user_id, count(ca.ad_id) as "Roles Filled"
    FROM CANDAPPL_HISTORY_STAT_CHANGES ca
    JOIN ADVERTISEMENTS a on A.AD_ID = CA.AD_ID
    JOIN USERS u on a.user_id = U.USER_PK_ID
    WHERE ca.acc_id = '150500'
    AND new_status = 'H'
    AND old_status != 'H'
    AND ca.CREATED_DT >= TO_DATE('2020-08-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND ca.CREATED_DT <= TO_DATE('2020-08-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    GROUP BY u.USER_PK_ID,u.user_id
    ORDER BY count(ca.ad_id) DESC;
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: You can replace the related parts with these : `ca.CREATED_DT BETWEEN date'2020-08-12' AND date'2020-08-19'` and `ORDER BY "Roles Filled" DESC` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding of the problem is correct, you want the average time of hire per user id. That can be done by doing a groupby on the userid, something like below

```
    SELECT  u.USER_PK_ID,  u.user_id, round(AVG(ca.CREATED_DT - r.submitted_dt, 1)) as "AVG Time to hire"
        FROM CANDAPPL_HISTORY_STAT_CHANGES ca
        JOIN ADVERTISEMENTS a on A.AD_ID = CA.AD_ID
        JOIN USERS u on a.user_id = U.USER_PK_ID
        JOIN REPLIES r on CA.CAND_ID = R.CAND_ID and CA.AD_ID = R.AD_ID 
        WHERE ca.acc_id = '150500'
        AND new_status = 'H'
        AND old_status != 'H'
        AND (r.submitted_dt is not null or r.referrer like '%(ATSi)%')
        AND ca.CREATED_DT >= TO_DATE('2020-08-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        AND ca.CREATED_DT <= TO_DATE('2020-08-19', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY u.USER_PK_ID,  u.user_id
```

Comment: yes i think this is correct but needed the avg changed to this round(AVG(ca.CREATED_DT - r.submitted_dt), 1) and removed the AND u.USER_PK_ID = '504407'

Comment: I have updated the query as per your suggestion, please accept the answer. Thanks